# Scaling Model in XNA, keep position

Tags: xna, 3d, matrix, 3d-meshes, transformation

I am trying to create a little fun 3D game in XNA, but I am having some problems with scaling my models. I use models from random sites, so my battleship is for an example 10 times larger than my planet.

I thought I had found out how to scale my model, but it does not show up when I do, or the coordinates get really messed up. Is there a way to scale my models but still keep the same position system?

Here is my model base class.

```
public class BaseModel
{
    protected Matrix world = Matrix.Identity;
    protected Matrix RotationMatrix = Matrix.Identity;
    protected Model model;
    protected float scale = 1.0f;
    protected Vector3 direction;

    public Vector3 Position
    {
        get
        {
            return world.Translation;
        }
        set
        {
            world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(value);
        }
    }

    public BaseModel(Model model, Vector3 position, float scale = 1)
        : this(model, position, Vector3.Zero, Matrix.Identity, scale)
    {
    }
    public BaseModel(Model model, Vector3 position, Vector3 direction, float scale = 1)
        : this(model, position, direction, Matrix.Identity, scale)
    {
    }
    public BaseModel(Model model, Vector3 position, Vector3 direction, Matrix rotationMatrix, float scale = 1)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.Position = position;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.RotationMatrix = rotationMatrix;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        world *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(direction);
    }

    public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime, Camera camera)
    {
        Matrix[] modelTransforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);
        Matrix wworld = GetWorld();

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * wworld;
                effect.View = camera.view;
                effect.Projection = camera.projection;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }

    public virtual Matrix GetWorld()
    {
        return RotationMatrix * world * Matrix.CreateScale(scale);
    }

    public virtual Model GetModel()
    {
        return model;
    }

    public virtual bool CollidesWith(Model otherModel, Matrix otherWorld)
    {
        // Loop through each ModelMesh in both objects and compare
        // all bounding spheres for collisions
        foreach (ModelMesh myModelMeshes in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh hisModelMeshes in otherModel.Meshes)
            {
                if (myModelMeshes.BoundingSphere.Transform(
                    GetWorld()).Intersects(
                    hisModelMeshes.BoundingSphere.Transform(otherWorld)))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the scale to be in the world matrix and not in the model matrix? I suggest simply putting `return Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * model;` in `GetModel()`.

Comment: @SamHocevar `Model` is not a matrix. It's a XNA class that represents a collection of 3D meshes and bones.

Comment: The `world` variable has a misleading name, and from the context, I'd recommend changing it to `TranslationMatrix` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Swap the order of multiplication in the `GetWorld` method so that the scale comes first:

```
public virtual Matrix GetWorld()
{
    return Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * RotationMatrix * world;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Scale * rotate * translate

```
public virtual Matrix GetWorld()
{
    return Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * RotationMatrix * world; 
}
```

when scale is after translate, it scales the translation values. Think SRT when building a final matrix.